# how to parse a single td when td is in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I am using this script to create an orderlist with articles.

```
<form>
    <table>
        <?php
        include ('artikel_lijst.php');
        foreach($artikels as $artikel => $art){
        ?>
            <tr>    
            <td>
            <?php echo $artikel."\n";?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php echo '&euro; '.number_format($art, 2)."\n";?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtinput[]" size="3" />
            </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Output" />
</form>
<?php
//post and calculate
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $totaal = 0;
    foreach($_POST['txtinput'] as $postartikel => $val){
        if(!empty($_POST['txtinput'][$postartikel])){
            echo array_keys($artikels)[$postartikel].':&nbsp; Aantal: '.$val. "&nbsp;&nbsp;Subtotaal: &euro;: " .number_format($artikels[array_keys($artikels)[$postartikel]] * $val, 2). "<br>\n";
        }
        $totaal += $artikels[array_keys($artikels)[$postartikel]] * $val;
    }
    echo 'Totaal: '.number_format($totaal, 2);
}
```

**artikel_lijst.php**

```
$artikels = array(
'cola' => 1.2,
'fanta' => 1.3,
'mineral water' => 1.5,
    'hamburger' => 2.5,
    'cheeseburger' => 2.5,
    'milkshake' => 2.5,

 );
```

As you can see, the table rows and the table data are created by the foreach.
My question: how can i, lets say after 5 articles, make an single row within **List 2**

```
<tr><td>List 2</td></tr>
// parse again 5 rows
<tr><td>List 3</td></tr>
// now parse 8 rows
<tr><td>List 4</td></tr>
```

So i want manually place on some places in the table an extra row which is the heading of a new list of articles below of it

Comment: You have to specify some criteria for when you want to add an additional row.  The criteria must be in the data structure.   Unless "user of this script user" posses  telekinetic powers to communicate with PHP. But the telepathic extension is not yet available in the current release of  PHP.

Comment: So i think this is not possible at all. I have to create  the form manually and get him out of the foreach??

Comment: You need to specify the criteria and include that criteria in the data.

Answer (score 0):

in your loop, just use "modulo" :

```
$i = 0;
foreach($_POST['txtinput'] as $postartikel => $val) {
  if($i % 5 == 0) {
    // Something that will be executed only 1 in 5 times
  }

  ...
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: I can do that, but there comes an extra row after 5 rows. The problem is, the user of this script wants sometimes an extra row after 5 articles, and sometimes after 8 or 9 articles.